# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/license/LicenseContentException While deploying mule war file to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am facing error while deploying mule war file to tomcat. 
I got following error

```
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from simplewebapp.xml; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/license/LicenseContentException (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$2.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
```

My flow is as follow

```
 <flow name="simplewebappFlow1" doc:name="simplewebappFlow1">
        <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/rig" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Servlet"/>
        <response>
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        </response>
        <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce" query="dsql:SELECT Id,Name FROM Account" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="List_Account__To_CSV" doc:name="List&lt;Account&gt; To CSV"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/Test" outputPattern="test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
```

I call this flow on webpage

```
<a href="./services/rig">click</a>
```

When I click on this at that time I got following error...

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Property mule.context not set on ServletContext
    org.mule.transport.servlet.AbstractReceiverServlet.setupMuleContext(AbstractReceiverServlet.java:125)
    org.mule.transport.servlet.AbstractReceiverServlet.init(AbstractReceiverServlet.java:115)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
```

How can I solve this error??

Thanks

Comment: Which war version are you using?

Comment: You are using Data Mapper, which is an EE feature: did MuleSoft grant you access to the EE Maven repo so you can pull in the required dependencies (including the license checker) when building your WAR?

Comment: Thanks for reply .. Which more connectors,or components, or transformers are belong to EE feature???

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a licensed MuleEE and you have already read [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat) and [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Server+Based+Hot+Deployment).

If that is true then you are missing a library called truelicense.

Comment: Thanks for reply .. Which more connectors,or components, or transformers are belong to EE feature???